# have any idea how can create or import product in magento-2?

Tags: product, import, magento2

I want to be a insert or import product in magento-2 ? Please if you have any thought share with me.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any problem with this functionality?

Answer (score 3):

You can find sample of csv file for import product on System -> Import -> Choose Products and "Download Sample CSV file". Detailed description of each column in our [The Complete Guide to Magento 2 Product Import](https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-magento-2-product-import-export.html)

[image]

Please note that since Magento 2 still in development, some bugs on import process still exist, but in general it works good with all new out of box features like import custom options, images from external URL etc.

Sample CSV files for Magento 2 - https://github.com/firebearstudio/magento2-import-export-sample-files

Answer (score 0):

### Importing product with images in Magento 2 :

Add new Product if no existing product is there in existing Magento store.

Go to *System > Data Transfer > Export*

Select entity type as product and click on on continue button that is in the bottom of the page. Once you click on continue button you can download the csv file of exported products . Use the exported sheet for reference to fill the values and then fill yours values accordingly , fill image name with file extension as .jpg or .png etc as mentioned in this screenshot:

[image]

then go to var folder create one folder having name ( import ) and place the image having same name as mentioned in the import csv file and then

Go to *System > Data Transfer > Import*

and select entity type as an product select import behavior as per yours need and then browse for file from Select File to Import browse option after this enter the path of import folder in our case it  is var/import in the  Images File Directory text box as mentioned in the following screenshot :

[image]

Then click on check data button on top right corner. If you did everything correct you will get this screen

[image]

Click import button and then do reindexing using CMD:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

and then flush the cache:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

and then check yours frontend it will show imported products with images.

Comment: any thoughts on this question - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/337077/magento-2-prevent-stopping-import-execution-magento-2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Uploading of a single product in Magento 2 is not an issue, but it would take more time to upload the product in bulk by this method. Through default Magento 2 import export method, you can do it for bulk by saving your precious time.

Let’s go through default Magento 2 import method

- Login to your Magento 2 admin panel and navigate to **System > Import**

[image: Import Method]

- In the Import section select what kind of data you want to import through **Entity Type**
- Through **Import Behavior** you can define the action of your imported file whether to you want to **Add/Update** the product or **Replace** and **Delete** the selected import products
- During the import, if an error occurs you can select to **Stop on Error** or **Skip erro**r entries of your Magento 2 import export file
- In **Allowed Errors Count** you can define no of errors on which Magento import export process would be halted
- Through **Field separator**, you will define symbol through which system would separate the fields from Magento 2 import export file
- In **Multiple value separator**, you will define symbol through which system would separate the values from your Imported file
- In **Select File to Import** choose the file from which you want to import data

**Suggestion**: The imported CSV file should be in UTF-8 format, you can create your own such format file but I would recommend you to Download Sample File and make necessary changes in the downloaded file or make your own such file.

Comment: any thoughts on this question - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/337077/magento-2-prevent-stopping-import-execution-magento-2