# Magento 2 : Prevent stopping import execution in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, importexport

I am not able to find the code which is responsible for breaking import csv execution
from magento import tool in backend.

I do not want to terminate csv execution, even if error occur.

Any thoughts on this please ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an error to stop the import process you can try the Validation Strategy select set to Skip error entries option

[image]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: That does not work because there may be critical error in processing csv so $this->importModel->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated() will return true

Comment: I just want to know which method terminates the execution

Comment: ok Devhs, Is your CSV is proper? Are you facing an issue because of a PHP critical error? Did you check your log ( exception or debugging  ) file? State error you are getting in your question? Brother needs a little more info. Thanks

Comment: I also did not found the code, it will gives errors but allow to import. CSV is also correct but when we throw error from code in custom import it should disable import button. @devhs if you find please post answer

Comment: @Ankit - What is an error? Please can you report here

Comment: The error I threw from my code actually. What I want is to custom import and when I throw error import button should not be visible